# How to fill and join 3 sub tables with data contained in an other main table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following main_table, already filled with data:

[image]

From this main_table I want to fill and join 3 sub-tables (which are empty) with data contained in the `main_table` using foreign key, in order to get something like that:

[image]

I have difficulty to understand which SQL code is needed to fill the 3 sub-tables, and to generate the join between them.

I tried to use the following code, but it does not create any junction between tables. I imagine I have to use "JOIN ... ON" somewhere, but I've difficulty to understand how should I do it.

```
INSERT INTO table_town
    (name_town)
SELECT name_town
FROM table_main
GROUP BY name_town
ORDER BY name_town;
```

Data for a reproducible example:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table_main (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  price INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  house VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  name_town VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO table_main 
(price  , house ,   name_town       ) 
VALUES 
(100    ,   'A' ,   'DAISYTOWN'     ),
(1500   ,   'C' ,   'PRICETOWN'     ),
(400    ,   'B',    'QUEENSTOWN'    ),
(200    ,   'D',    'JACKSTOWN'     ),
(150    ,   'E',    'JACKSTOWN'     ),
(400    ,   'F',    'PRICETOWN'     ),
(200    ,   'A',    'DAISYTOWN'     ),
(700    ,   'B',    'QUEENSTOWN'    ),
(800    ,   'G',    'QUEENSTOWN'    ),
(2500   ,   'H',    'HYPERTOWN'     )
;

CREATE TABLE table_town (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name_town VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE table_house (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  table_town_id INT NOT NULL,
  house VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE table_sale_estate (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  table_house_id INT NOT NULL,
  price INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE table_sale_estate ADD CONSTRAINT `table_sale_estate_fk_table_house` FOREIGN KEY (`table_house_id`) REFERENCES `table_house`(`id`);

ALTER TABLE table_house ADD CONSTRAINT `table_house_fk_table_town` FOREIGN KEY (`table_town_id`) REFERENCES `table_town`(`id`);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM table_main;
```

| id | price | house | name_town |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | A | DAISYTOWN |
| 2 | 1500 | C | PRICETOWN |
| 3 | 400 | B | QUEENSTOWN |
| 4 | 200 | D | JACKSTOWN |
| 5 | 150 | E | JACKSTOWN |
| 6 | 400 | F | PRICETOWN |
| 7 | 200 | A | DAISYTOWN |
| 8 | 700 | B | QUEENSTOWN |
| 9 | 800 | G | QUEENSTOWN |
| 10 | 2500 | H | HYPERTOWN |

---

**Query #2**

```
INSERT INTO table_town
    (name_town)
SELECT name_town
FROM table_main
GROUP BY name_town
ORDER BY name_town;
```

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT * FROM table_town;
```

| id | name_town |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | DAISYTOWN |
| 2 | HYPERTOWN |
| 3 | JACKSTOWN |
| 4 | PRICETOWN |
| 5 | QUEENSTOWN |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/25NVMvazYrAAmvDAk7uxMo/4)

I'm trying to fill the 3 sub-tables with data coming from the `table_main`, making sure that relations between sub-tables across foreign keys are working without losing data.

As shown above, I've tried to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` to fill the table_town.

I suppose I should now use a `JOIN ... ON` clause to fill and join the 3 sub-tables correctly, but I have some difficulties to understand how should I write the correct code to do it, and in which order should I do it.

I'm beginner in SQL. I will do my best to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must fill the table `table_town` from `table_main`, but there is no need for aggregation.
All you need is the distinct values of `name_town`:

```
INSERT INTO table_town (name_town)
SELECT DISTINCT name_town
FROM table_main
ORDER BY name_town;
```

Then, fill `table_house` by joining `table_main` to `table_town`:

```
INSERT INTO table_house(table_town_id, house)
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, m.house
FROM table_main m INNER JOIN table_town t
ON t.name_town = m.name_town
ORDER BY m.house;
```

Finally fill `table_sale_estate` by joining `table_main` to `table_house`:

```
INSERT INTO table_sale_estate(table_house_id, price)
SELECT h.id, m.price
FROM table_main m INNER JOIN table_house h
ON h.house = m.house 
ORDER BY m.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4563df664c1a1916660aaf0d995845f).

Note that the `ORDER BY` clauses I use in my code, although they seem to work, they do not guarantee the order of the rows in the tables because there is no such order.

Comment: thanks forpas. I'm currently trying to absorb the kownledge coming from your solution. I notice, you include `MIN(t.id)` clause in the second step (filling table_house). But you did not replicate the same principle for the third step (filling table_sale_estate). I've difficulty understand the function of this clause, and why it would be fair for step 2 and not for step 3. Is it possible for you to give a little highlight on it (explanation) ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @anch I used aggregation for `table_house` to get distinct rows from the join, but don't get confused, the same result can be achieved with DISTINCT. I edited.

Comment: Thank you forpas. It's perfect. I get now the all picture. It's great. Clap your hands and say "yeah !". Respect. Thanks a lot again.